# How to draw same bar plot multi time with different values with out adding the new value on it using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have NumPy array that has 899 tensors. Each tensor presents classifier results.
For examples:
tensor([2.6309e-10, 1.4486e-05, 1.4576e-07, 9.9999e-01, 3.6547e-08])
The title is ['Unknown', 'Person', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'House']
I want to draw a bar plot for each tensor and save it as .jpg.
The problem is that when I draw the first is okay but the next tensor will draw on the top of the old one, Which is what I don't want to do.
The question:
How to draw a bar plot for each tensor without drawing on the top of the old ones?

The Code:

```
path = ""
langs = ['Unknown', 'Person', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'House']

if os.path.exists(path):
    logits= torch.from_numpy(np.load(path))
    for i in range(len(logits)):
      logit = 0
      logit = logits[i]
      logit = logit[1:]
      print(logit)
      plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 7)
      plt.bar(langs,logit)
      plt.savefig('Output/subject/' + str(i)+'.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.clf()` after `plt.savefig()`. It clears the plot after every step.

```
path = ""
langs = ['Unknown', 'Person', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'House']

if os.path.exists(path):
    logits= torch.from_numpy(np.load(path))
    for i in range(len(logits)):
      logit = 0
      logit = logits[i]
      logit = logit[1:]
      print(logit)
      plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 7)
      plt.bar(langs,logit)
      plt.savefig('Output/subject/' + str(i)+'.jpg')
      plt.clf()
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was helpful